# Socket.io on Heroku

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, express, socket.io

I have a slight problem with use of Node.js and socket.io on Heroku. It works fine locally but as soon as I push it to Heroku and go on the website it gives me the application error page. Looking at the logs there is no explicit error but I have a feeling what it might be. When I run it locally, I use `sudo node server` to start the app. Just `node server` gives the same effect as that on heroku.

So basically, my question is: How do I get Heroku to run in sudo mode, or how can I remove the need to use sudo altogether?

Apologies as this is my first time using socket.io, so I am a bit unfamiliar with the workings of the library.

P.S. I am using Express 3.

Comment: I think we need more specifics.  You shouldn't need to use `sudo node server` (unless `server` is doing something that requires root permissions like listening on a privileged port which is probably a bad idea).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would check into the port you are using. On a normal ubuntu machine for example you may have to use sudo for low numbered ports (such as port 80). Besides that Heroku has a lot of load balancing going on, so the port you will use to connect to the service may not be the same as the port you tell the instance to listen on.

I would try using port 5000 as per this example from Heroku
[Nodejs with sockets](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/node-websockets)

Comment: Ok, I did what you said and it didn't work until I added a `.listen(process.env.PORT || 5000)` but thank you for your help :)

Comment: I'm sorry it didn't work right off - do you know what port the app is actually listening on with Heroku in the end?

that notation this || that just means that if this is undefined, then use that

Comment: Yes, I realised at a later point. I'd never really thought about it before but I realised that if Heroku wanted to run it on a specific port, it'd be stored in process.env.PORT but otherwise I could use 5000. I think before I was trying to force it to run on a specific port.